# How to decide if left hand or right hand based on the accelerometer of the phone

Tags: android, iphone, accelerometer, kinect

Is there any possibility in obtaining information about the hand which holds the kinect based on the accelerometer data?

If not, is there any posibility for obtaining information about the hand which holds the device. I start with the assumption that I am using an iPhone or and Android based phone.

I want to use this data with kinect so that I can display something in the hand which holds the phone, by using the joint tracking provided by the kinect device.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such device that can indicate which hand is holding the device. The best I could think of, is if the accelerometer or gyroscope indicates that the device is tilted to the left, then it is more likely to be held by the right hand (vice versa). This is only based on my understanding of the hand joint and the way I hold my phone. Even then, it is different when you are holding while talking/ holding it while browsing. So to sum up, impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *easy* way to detect which-handedness, but I bet that left and right handholding produce different accelerometer signatures over time, which you can then test against via machine learning.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't any device which i know of that is able to detect which hand is holding the device by simply holding it.

are you trying to hold the kinect? you shouldn't do this since it will lead to inaccurate reading.

i assume that you are not holding the kinect, then in that case, your kinect would be able to tell which hand is holding the kinect.